# 1 динамическая страница или 4 статических.

Tags: seo

Имеется сайт объявлений. 
в нем на главной 4 рубрики Купить, продать, сдать, снять. 
На данной момент страница динамическая, т.е. в при выборе какого-либо пункта в адрес браузера методом ГЕТ передается параметр.

Но подумал, ведь если сделать отдельо 4 страницы, то можно прописать 4 разных тайтла и заголовка, что лучше для поисковика. 
Развейте мои сомнения. Не хотелось бы создавать 4 дубликата одной страницы.

Answer (score 1):

Если при выборе есть параметр GET и страницы динамические, почему и тайтл не брать откуда-нибудь, желательно оттуда же где и контент страницы.

Проблема в чем?

4 разные страницы, 4 разных тайтла, кивордса и дескрипшена.

Вопрос немного не правильно задан, мне кажется.

Comment: да, можно сделать так, чтобы при переходе на эту динамическу страницу, в зависимости от парамента передавались нужный тайтл кейвордс и дескрипшн. Но Будет ли их хранить поисковый паук у себя на сервере?
Он что  будет перебирать все возможные параметры , которые я могу передать методом ГЕТ?

Comment: Я что-то не понял, зачем гетом передавать остальные параметры?
Передаешь только параметр alias страницы, в php проверяешь есть ли такое значение, если есть то показываешь страницу с нужными параметрами.

Comment: Наверное я неправильно изъясняюсь. 
Файл у меня всего один. index.php. А значит и title у него один. 
остальных 3х страниц как таковых не существует. Паук их проиндексирует?

Comment: ?? с чего он один??? может быть и не один.


    <? if ($page == 'test') {
    $mytitle = 'title1';
    } else {
    $mytitle = 'title2';
    }
    ?>
    
    <html>
    <head>
    <title><?php echo $mytitle; ?></title>
    </head>
    <body />
    </html>

Comment: паук индексирует html начинку, а не то, что у вас в пхп... вы что? вбоюсь представить как вы статику генерите.....

Answer (score 0):

Поисковику по большей части уже давно пофигу на мета теги. Как вам кажется логичнее с человеческой точки зрения так и делайте.

Comment: @Roman Moiseev, поисковику может быть и "пофигу", но при выдаче результатов при поисковом запросе, пользователю гораздо приятней наблюдать не голую ссылку, а еще и описание того, что ты увидишь, перейдя по этой ссылке. Именно это описание и береться из *meta description*